# SQL query returns data but ResultSet is empty

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset, is-empty

i have searched in so questions but there is nothing like my problem. I've this easy SQL

```
SELECT MIN(date) 
FROM table1 
WHERE date > date1 (obviously date1 is a parameter)
```

i tried to catch the empty resultSet with if(rset.next()) but it didn't work because MIN() function returns EVER 1 row though it is an empty row, so what can i do to catch it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot prove my idea with running system but I would try to use wasNull() on result set:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    date = rs.getDate(1);
    if (rs.wasNull()) {
     // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work because when you try to read a null column an exception comes (java.lang.NullPointerException) and at the if instruction isn't run..

Comment: Hm, pity. It is tough question

Comment: solved by "myself" (thanks to Jens).. i've added a count() and when the result is 0 the resultset is empty

    SELECT MIN(date), COUNT(id) 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE date > date1 
HAVING COUNT(id) > 0

Thanks for all repliers..